# Why does a copy occur in ternary statement?

Tags: c++

I can't quite figure out why a copy is occurring here. Consider the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(int value) : value(value) {}
    X(const X &x) : value(x.value) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;    
    }
    int value = 0;  
};

struct Z {
    Z(const X &x) : x(x) {}
    const X &get_x() const {return x;}
    X x;    
};

X get_x(const Z &z) {
    return z.get_x();
}

int main() {
    X x1(2);
    Z z1(x1);
    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    const X &x2 = (true) ? z1.get_x() : get_x(z1);    // (1)
    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    const X &x3 = (true) ? z1.get_x() : z1.get_x();   // (2)
}
```

The output is:

```
copy
----
copy
----
```

Why does a copy occur when the result of the false statement changes from a function returning a copy vs a function returning a const-reference, when both should take the true condition? I would have thought that in both (1) and (2), whatever is in the false condition should not have a side effect.

Comment: think of the ternary operator as a whole having a return value. The `true` condition side has a reference; the `false` condition side has a value. The combined type is a value. The dead-code elimination happens later and cannot change the semantics anyway

Comment: C++ Standard [expr.cond] paragraph 4: "if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an attempt is made to form an implicit conversion sequence […]  that conversion is applied to the chosen operand and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this subclause"

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks for your intuition example. This should probably be a separate question, but is there a way to get the behaviour of no copying occurring? A function taking a const reference can bind to either an rvalue or const lvalue, and I would have assumed I could get similar behaviour with a simple ternary operator.

Comment: Making the condition `true` at compile time does not change the fact that the types of *both* possible results are considered when determining the type of the result of the ternary expression.  Since one possible result is `X &` and the other is `X`, the result of the ternary has type `X`, not `X &`.   The only effect of the `true` in your ternary is ensuring that the `false` expression (`get_x(z1)`) is *never evaluated* - but the presence of that expression means its *type* is still considered.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it. The thing is: If one side is a value and the other is not, the program would have to keep track of which side was true to know if it should invoke a destructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type, and more importantly here the value category of `? :` has to be determined at compile-time.

If both operands are lvalues, then the result is also an lvalue, and all is well (no extra copy).

But if one operand is a prvalue (aka a temporary object), then the whole `? :` must also return a prvalue. So if the branch taken is originally not a prvalue, a temporary object must be constructed to get one, hence a copy.

---

Note that I'm intentionally wording this in terms of value categories, rather than reference-ness of types, because [expressions can't have refernece types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1).

Answer (score 3):

To extend my comment:

> but is there a way to get the behaviour of no copying occurring?

Not directly. The thing is: If one side is a value and the other is not, the program would have to keep track of which side was true to know if it should invoke a destructor.

However, you can achieve this by assigning to a helper variable.

```cpp
int main() {
    X x1(2);
    Z z1(x1);
    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    std::optional<X> opt;
    const X &x2 = (true) ? z1.get_x() : *(opt = get_x(z1));    // (1)
    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    const X &x3 = (true) ? z1.get_x() : z1.get_x();   // (2)
}
```

prints

```
copy
----
----
```

the `false` case prints 2 copies.

```
copy
----
copy
copy
----
```

1. To create the return value of `get_x`
2. To construct the value inside the `std::optional`.

The first is part of the interface and unavoidable. The second can be avoided by declaring a move constructor. However, since there is no operation that implements "emplace by calling this function", two constructors are required.

Comment: I didn't consider `std::optional` as a use case for this. However, if `(1)` evaluates to false instead, the copy constructor is called twice. Do you know why this is the case? `opt=get_x(z1)` should be one call, but I don't see where the 2nd call would be since the false branch should return a const reference (since it does so on the true condition, and both sides need to have the same type)

Comment: @JakeTuero edited the answer. It took me a moment to figure it out, too

Comment: Thanks. I believe I can get away with none or one copy by redesigning my codebase and doing the check elsewhere, but this was quite helpful for my understanding.